# c++ do something as soon as an object "changes"

Tags: c++, object, event-handling

I'm working on a project that reads MIDI-data from an external USB-device. I don't want to get too specific here, but this is roughly how it looks like:

I've got all my incoming MIDI-events stacked inside an object, let's call it "in". Now, to get the next MIDI-event from the stack, I first have to check if "in" has at least one event on the stack using a member function.

Is there a way to automatically process all the events on the stack as soon as there are new ones, without having to check everytime?
I'm thinking of something similar to an event-listener (sorry if this sounds stupid, I'm a beginner).

Comment: how do the events get put on the stack?  if the class had a method which was called to push the events on the stack, then that method could also notify listeners that a new item was available.

Comment: Have a look at the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to automatically process all the events on the stack as soon as there are new ones, without having to check everytime? I'm thinking of something similar to an event-listener (sorry if this sounds stupid, I'm a beginner).

When your are using stack the code may look like:

```
// producer
stack.push(midi_event);

// consumer
while(!stack.empty())
    process_event(stack.pop());
```

Instead of using the stack as a communication queue the producer can keep a pointer to the consumer (callback interface) and push the event directly to consumer like this:

```
// set-up the producer-consumer callback
Consumer consumer;
Producer producer(&consumer); // saves Consumer* into a member-variable
// start the event processing loop
while(producer_or_an_event_loop_object.wait_and_dispatch())
    ; // loop till wait_and_dispatch() returns false


// Producer::produce_event()
this->consumer->process_event(midi_event);
```

Boost.signals library is designed for this kind of problem and has [a nice tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/signals/tutorial.html) on the subject.

Answer (score -3):

The observer pattern is for this purpose.

Comment: At least link to the Wikipedia page or something.

Comment: mmmm. How is this answer not equivalent to just blurting back "you want to do something whenever an event occurs". This answer is in the "correct but useless" department for the OP